# Facebook permissions: How to check if the user has already allowed publish_stream for your application

Tags: javascript, facebook

How do I check if the user has already allowed your application to publish on his stream (to avoid the momentarily popup menu). Currently I'm simply using this JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    <!--
        Facebook.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream,read_stream');
    //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Users.hasAppPermission to check if a user has those permissions.

General API: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.hasAppPermission

Javascript library: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.ApiClient.users_hasAppPermission

Comment: This is using the soon to be deprecated REST API, see below for my answer how to do it with Graph API.

Answer (score 14):

The right way to do this with the Graph API is to use User.permissions.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpermissions

So with the JS SDK you can do:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', checkAppUserPermissions);

function checkAppUserPermissions(response) {
    console.log("User permissions response", response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

abronte is right, use hasAppPermission, as you can see in this tuorial:

> http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/17/posting-to-facebook-from-website-with-facebook-connect/

Answer (score 0):

Building off AdamB's answer, if you're using the JavaScript Graph SDK, you can still make calls to the REST API (the function [users.hasAppPermission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.hasAppPermission) is part of the REST API).

Go to *[FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.api/)* for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Using FB sdk, you can simple use the "/me" endpoint to check for specific permission status.
For all the permission, make the permBundle to be null, permission status for all is returned in the response.

```
final Bundle permBundle = new Bundle();
permBundle.putCharSequence("permission", "publish_actions");
GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/permissions", permBundle, HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                Log.d(TAG, "response: " + graphResponse.getJSONObject());
            }
        }
);
request.executeAsync();
```